# How to pass var to Select[(#colunm == value) &] construct

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, conditional, pure-function

I'm using a construct (more complex in fact as the `value_` should take a list) to select some entries from an association with criteria:

```
g[assoc_, value_]:= Select[(#column == value)&][assoc]
```

As you can see, `column` name is 'hardcoded', so it literally must be in `assoc`.
Is there a proper way to pass arbitrary `column_` name to function construct?

```
g[assoc_, value_, column_]
```

Now I could do some `g[assoc_, value_, #column]` but it seems ugly, and MMA marks it. Would be nice to combine somehow `#` with variable name.
Or some workaround?

Comment: `#[column] == value`?

Comment: @Kuba. Brilliant! It works))) Thank you! Should I delete it?

Comment: Question is slightly different but it boils down to the same thing. Let me know if you disagree with marking it duplicate.

Comment: @Kuba, I'm fine with dup